# Routing in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs, ember-old-router

I try to use routing in Ember.js, but it does not seem to be working properly.

The full code is [here on Github](https://github.com/baothy/emberJs-requireJs-testing-router/tree/), but a portion is below:

```
define(['ember', 'app/controllers/controller', 'app/views/view'], function (ember, controller, view) {
    var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
        root: Ember.State.extend({
            index: Ember.State.extend({
                // location: Ember.Location.create({style: 'hash'}),
                location: 'hash',
                enableLogging: true,
                route: '/',
                redirectsTo: 'news.index'
            }),
            news: Ember.State.extend({
                route: '/news',
                // showPost : Ember.State.transitionTo('post'),
                test: Ember.ViewState.extend({
                    route: '/test',
                    view: view.appendTo('body')
                }),
                index: Ember.ViewState.extend({
                    route: '/',
                    view: null
                })
            })
        })
    });
    var router = Router.create({});
    return router;
});
```

Comment: What is the error that you're having? The routes are not being followed properly? Please give some more output

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to change your code to this:

```
define(['ember', 'app/controllers/controller', 'app/views/view'], function (ember, controller, view) {
    var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
        // These are properties of Ember.Router and should be defined here
        location: 'hash',
        enableLogging: true,

        root: Ember.State.extend({
            index: Ember.State.extend({
                route: '/',
                redirectsTo: 'news.index'
            }),
            news: Ember.State.extend({
                route: '/news',
                // showPost : Ember.State.transitionTo('post'),
                test: Ember.ViewState.extend({
                    route: '/test',
                    view: view.appendTo('body')
                }),
                index: Ember.ViewState.extend({
                    route: '/',
                    view: null
                })
            })
        })
    });
    var router = Router.create({});
    return router;
});
```

Let me know if that works.

**Update**

Actually you should not be using ViewState either. It's being depreciated. Follow the guide http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/.

Comment: Hey Roy, thanks for the reply. Acgtually I figured it out why it didn't work. I made some changes to the router and it works now. You are right, I shouldn't use Viewstate anymore and instead use Ember.Route (with the latest Ember.js). you can have a look at https://github.com/baothy/amberEx1